# How to pass numpy array values from python script to .NET?

Tags: c#, python, .net, ironpython, python.net

I need to call Python Script inside .NET (C#) tests and get numpy array values from that script. What is the best way to do this? Would the IronPython be appropriate way to do this or this is a better way?

Comment: You can try pythonnet to bridge CPython+numpy with .NET or Mono: https://github.com/pythonnet/pythonnet

Comment: There are some closed issues on converting from python objects to CLR objects dynamically on the pythonnet github here: https://github.com/pythonnet/pythonnet/issues/484 and here https://github.com/pythonnet/pythonnet/issues/623 Basically this guy wrote his own converter and stated an example on the issue, but you can find his code on https://github.com/yagweb/pythonnetLab/blob/master/pynetLab/PyConverter.cs as well as the example in the TestPyConverter file https://github.com/yagweb/pythonnetLab/blob/master/Test/TestPyConverter.cs